# Adwords api report without download

Tags: api, criteria-api, google-ads-api

I'm working with Adwords API, I already can download reports like: all keywords with impressions, clics, ctr, conversions, etc...

The problem is, I need to show this report on our web tool when the user set the date range.

Now I'm doing this: The user selects Start Date 01/09/2014 End Date 15/09/2014, I call Adwords Api, download CSV, parsing it, and then show the results on the screen, but this way is not optimal and I would like to know how to call the API and get the results "at the moment", getting an XML or JSON without download a file.

Is it possible??

The only way I found was calling CampaignService class.. getting all campaigns, then for each campaign calling AdgroupService for get all Adgroups, then keywords.... It's really impractical.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It appears in recent versions of the libary they created a function (getAsString()) so we can achieve this:

```
$reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
$reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReport($reportDefinition);

//Normal way of downloading to file
//$reportDownloadResult->saveToFile($filePath);
//printf("Report with name '%s' was downloaded to '%s'.\n",
//    $reportDefinition->getReportName(), $filePath);

//New way by calling getAsString();
$reportAsString = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
echo $reportAsString;
```

Old suggestions about passing null as the $filePath no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get XML without downloading file. Just set `$path` to `Null` when calling `ReportUtils::DownloadReport()` and it returns you response without saving it to file.

Comment: This might have worked in the past, but does not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The AdWords API library (as of v201506) allows you to set the download_format to one of CSVFOREXCEL, CSV, TSV, XML, GZIPPED_CSV, or GZIPPED_XML. It unfortunately does not support JSON, even if you ask to download the report data (not as a file).

Answer (score 0):

```
$reportAsString = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($reportAsString);
```